# Making SystemJS use angular2 bundle?

Tags: angular, systemjs

I'm trying to use angular2 in a Chrome extension and it isn't recognizing that I've loaded the angular2 bundle.  Here's my script tags in the file `/www/popup.html`:

```
<script src="lib/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/system.src.js"></script>

<!-- bundles should be used -->
<script src="lib/js/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/router.dev.js"></script>

<script src="app/pages/popup-page.js"></script>
```

In `/www/app/pages/popup-page.js` it will work if I setup the paths to the angular2 and rxjs source:

```
System.config({
  defaultJSExtensions: true, // Will prepend .js to the module names

  paths: {
    'angular2/*': '/node_modules/angular2/*', // finds
    'rxjs/*': '/node_modules/rxjs/*',         // finds
    '*': '/www/app/*'
  },
  packages: {
    "app": {
      format: 'register',
      defaultExtension: 'js',
    }
  }
});
```

But I don't want to have it load each of those javascript files individually, or even include them in my extension.  It looks like those bundles should register themselves when the scripts load.

1. If I don't include the path '*' to where my code is, I get a 'require is not defined' trying to run the scripts.
2. If I don't include the paths to angular2 and rxjs, I get the browser trying to load '/www/app/angular2/...' for each import instead of using the bundles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I think was `defaultJSExtensions`.  If I just change my `System.config` to this it works:

```
System.config({
  packages: {
    "app": {
      defaultExtension: 'js',
    }
  }
});
```

I just don't know of any place with documentation on what all these options are.  I've looked at these pages (and many more I didn't save links for) and not been able to find a reference or good explanation of what all the options are and do:

- [systemjs site](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs)

  - links to [paths implementation](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader/blob/master/docs/loader-config.md#paths-implementation) which is *useless*
  - links to [ecma draft](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts#august_24_2014_draft_rev_27) which has section 15.2 that is a nice reference for ES2015 modules, but not systemjs config

Answer (score 2):

If you load a bundle that has modules registered as system modules via `<script>` tag, you don't need anything else in `System.config` - it will resolve imports by registered names from memory.

By including `<script src="lib/js/angular2.dev.js"></script>` in your html file import statements like `import {Component} from 'angular2/core'` will work without any additional config.

Removing `path` options from `System.config` should resolve issue with angular imports. (`'*': '/www/app/*'` - this line basically maps everything to `/www/app` folder...).

To setup the paths for your own scripts use `map` option in `System.config.package["app"]`, [more info here](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#packages).

Comment: `popup-page` is not a module though I've written it in typescript.  It doesn't have any imports, it just calls `System.config` and then calls `System.import('./app/pages/popup-boot')`.  The examples I've seen have this code as an inline script in the html, but chrome extensions prohibit inline scripts so I made it a separate script and include it with a script tag.  `popup-boot` has the first statement `import {provide} from 'angular2/core';`, and I'm getting a 404 error with that trying to find `/www/app/angular2/core.js', so it is not recognizing the bundles for some reason.

Comment: I misunderstood how you use `popup-page.js`.. Try removing `path` config (this should resolve angular imports issue). Then try adding `map` for *app* package. something like `map: { app: "/www/app" }`.. to map imports for your app files to the folder where they are.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to map "app" and not "*", as described below:

```
System.config({
  defaultJSExtensions: true, // Will prepend .js to the module names

  paths: {
    'angular2/*': '/node_modules/angular2/*', // finds
    'rxjs/*': '/node_modules/rxjs/*',         // finds
    'app': '/www/app' // <------
  },
  packages: {
    "app": {
      format: 'register',
      defaultExtension: 'js',
    }
  }
});
```